# Granting Android Permissions - unknown value

Tags: java, android, permissions

Some time ago i added permission to my app about 'fine location' by some tutorial from internet. Everything works like i want, but i have question about 1 unexplained line:

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
```

Why is there value 101 ? Why not 102 or 200 ?

---

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 101;
```

.

```
   public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);

            } else {

            }
            return;
        }
```

.

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                        ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    return;
                }
                LatLng position = new LatLng(0, 0);


            } else {

                close();
            }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give it the value you want.It's worth doing the job onRequestPermissionResult to catch the requestCode

Comment: It's worth mentioning that each `requestPermissions()` call in an activity should get a distinct `int` value.

Comment: i added all code with 'permission' from my app, you can check

Comment: You are using 101 in the onRequestPermissionsResult.When you send a request for permission to the location, you are caught with that value because you sent it with that value.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation of [requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)), it says that the `requestCode` is for

> Application specific request code to match with a result reported to
>   onRequestPermissionsResult(int, String[], int[]). Should be >= 0.

What it means is that you'll explicitly specify this code to any values that you want, and you can then use this value to check if your request is successful or not in the callback `onRequestPermissionsResult`. An example, put this code in your Activity:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 101:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                //granted
            } else {
                //not granted
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

So back to your question, you can use 102, or 200, or whatever value you would like. But you should always check if the request is successful or not, by using the same code that you provide in the `requestPermissions` method.